# How can I add an i3 keybinding for i3lock?

Tags: i3, screensaver

On my Ubuntu box, I've added the line

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+l exec i3lock -c 000000
```

to my i3 config file.  After reloading with `$mod+Shift+r` and hitting `$mod+Shift+l`, I just get a `L` displayed in my terminal.  The screen doesn't lock.

Anticipating the "is it plugged in" question, I do have i3lock installed.

There is also no `~/.xsession-errors` file.

Comment: This can be closed.  I'm not sure what I changed but it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given,

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+l exec i3lock -c 000000
```

Works fine for me. Do you have `i3lock` installed? Does `i3lock -c 000000` work for you in isolation of the keybinding?

---

Also, I would suggest **NOT** using `i3lock`. What you're doing is turning your screen black, and keeping the backlight on. You should use something like `xscreensaver` which has `DPMS` settings and will actually turn the backlight off (saving power),

Here is a valid `~/.xscreensaver` that does what you want,

```
lock:           True
lockTimeout:    0:00:00
dpmsEnabled:    True
dpmsQuickOff:   True
dpmsStandby:    2:00:00
dpmsSuspend:    2:00:00
dpmsOff:        4:00:00
mode:           blank
```

Then you can bind it to `xscreensaver-command --lock` rather than `i3lock`

Comment: Yeah, the command works fine from the terminal.  I'll take a look at `xscreensaver`.